# Is %s the only format that will allow printf to display big integers correctly?

Tags: perl, printf, biginteger

I just spent an epoch figuring out that my big integer was fine and that [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html)'s `%d`/`%u` were not up to the task of displaying it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use bigint;
use List::Gen;

*factorial = do {use bigint; <[..*] 1, 1..>->code};

my $value = factorial(32);
printf "%d\n", $value;  # -1
printf "%u\n", $value;  # 18446744073709551615
printf "%s\n", $value;  # 263130836933693530167218012160000000
```

I wouldn't be surprised if the answer is no, just wanted to confirm it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was surprisingly hard to track down.  I didn't see anything obvious in the docs, so I went to the source.  The `printf` function is implemented (at the bottom of a long call stack) by the C function `Perl_sv_vcatpvfn_flags`.  It appears as if this function assumes the number will fit in an IV or a UV.  They are defined by

```
typedef IVTYPE IV;
typedef UVTYPE UV;
```

Which is in turn defined by (at least on my Perl, I think this is configurable)

```
#define IVTYPE          long            /**/
#define UVTYPE          unsigned long           /**/
```

So, if your number won't fit in a long, then (`%d`) or in an unsigned long (`%u`), then a string (`%s`) is your only option.  A bigger quesiton is why you are using `printf` in the first place.  Are you formatting these numbers in some way other than printing them?  If not, then `print` should just do the right thing.

Comment: There was no particular reason to use `printf` other than the fact that it was already there when I started feeding my process ginormous numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. `%s` is the only format for strings.

---

- `%%`: Obviously no.
- `%c`: Obviously no.
- `%s`: Yes.
- `%d`: Only if the number fits in a signed integer.
- `%u`, `%o`, `%x`, `%X`, `%b`, `%B`: Only if the number fits in a unsigned integer.
- `%e`, `%E`, `%f`, `%g`, `%G`, `%a`, `%A`: Only if the number fits in a floating point number.
- `%p`: Obviously no.
- `%n`: Obviously no.

Answer (score 4):

Given that you have to use a specific library for the purpose of manipulating such numbers, there is no reason to expect that the *builtin* `printf` would handle them. Instead, you can use the library's [conversion functions](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::BigInt#String-conversion-methods) such as `as_hex` or `bnstr`. If you just want to print the number, use `print "$value\n";`.

Comment: The bigint pragma is part of core Perl 5, I can see why (with no extra documentation) you might expect Perl 5 to handle it correctly.